# Como posso disponibilizar minha aplicação node em varios idiomas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, handlebars.js

Olá, possuo uma aplicação node que utiliza o express e handlebars, gostaria de disponibiliza-la em 3 idiomas diferentes (portugues, espanhol e ingles).

Eu consegui fazer isso criando um arquivo diferente para cada linguagem, mas acabou ficando muito bagunçado, e eu não tenho certeza se essa é a maneira correta.

```
    const renderLang = ['en', 'pt', 'es']
    const renderTitle = ['What is my IP?', 'Qual é o meu IP?', '¿Cual es mi IP?']

router.get('/lookup', function(req, res) {
    let getSubDomain = req.headers.host.split(`.`)
    let renderSelectLang = verifyLang(getSubDomain[0])

    res.render(renderSelectLang[0] + '/lookup', {lang: renderSelectLang[0], title: renderSelectLang[1]})
})

function verifyLang(subDomain) {
    let renderSelectLang = [renderLang[0], renderTitle[0]]

    if(subDomain == 'pt') {
        renderSelectLang = [renderLang[1], renderTitle[1]]
    } else if(subDomain == 'es') {
        renderSelectLang = [renderLang[2], renderTitle[2]]
    }

    return renderSelectLang
}
```

E também estou utilizando sub-dominios, um para cada linguagem 'pt' e 'es' e a rota padrão é em ingles.

Preciso de algum metodo mais eficiente para definir as linguagens mas não sei como fazer.

Eu pensei em criar um arquivo externo, como um JSON e armazenar as mensagens mas não sei se isso é correto e também não sei como pode ser feito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer isso seria utilizar um pacote chamado i18n. Você pode instalar e integrar ao seu Express. Ele vai criar uma pasta chamada "locales" em seu  projeto, e dentro você vai ter um arquivo Json com o nome do código da linguagem. Dentro dele, você vai ter um arquivo com o formato de chave/valor, ou seja, as chaves vão ser iguais para todos os idiomas, mudando apenas o valor de acordo com o idioma.

Todo o conteúdo de suas páginas vão ser variáveis, que você vai substituir de acordo com o idioma.

As rotas seriam únicas para qualquer linguagem.

O idioma ele vai pegar do navegador que está acessando (isso pode ser configurado).

Aqui tem um pequeno exemplo:

Express:

```js
var express = require('express'),
var I18n = require('i18n-2');
 
// Express 
app.configure(function() {
    // ...
 
    // Anexar propriedade i18n property para o objeto request
    // Vincular helpers para todos os templates
    I18n.expressBind(app, {
        // Configurar idiomas, em caso de idioma nao localizado o padrão é "en"
        locales: ['en', 'de']
    }));
 
    // Restante configuração express
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Controller:

```js
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res) {
        req.render("index", {
            title: req.i18n.__("My Site Title"),
            desc: req.i18n.__("My Site Description")
        });
    }
};
```

View:

```js
{% extends "page.swig" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ __("Welcome to: %s", title) }}</h1>
<p>{{ desc }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Recomendo você acompanhar a documentação:

https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node